# How to use a variable as a column name for a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

**I am unable to use a previously defined variable representing a column name in a SELECT statement and need some help.**

TABLE:

```
main | i1 | i2 ||..........| i24  | i25 |
.
. 
17 | 121 | 123| .........
19 | 123 | 212| .........   | 4832 | 56392 |
```

From a previous SELECT/SET statement @indent variable equaled 25. As I can't use an integer as a column name the columns are i1 - i25 in the tableindex. However when I attempt to use the @VARIABLE in the SELECT statment I get the following:

```
SET @colindex1=(CONCAT(i, @indent);    
SELECT @colindex1 FROM tableindex WHERE main=19;
```

RESULTS

```
| @colindex1 |
|  i25  |
```

SHOULD BE THE VALUE OF THE CELL:

```
| i25  |
| 56392|
```

So the next attach was to use a DECLARE statement.

```
DECLARE @colindex1 VARCHAR;
```

But I got the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare @colindex1 INT' at line 1

I need to combine my integer (25) value with the letter (i) for the column "i25' and then use it a SELECT statement. However I am failing at this point.

Can someone help

BASED ON ANSWER HERE IS A TEST USING THE SPECIFIED SYNTAX AND ERROR:

```
SET @indent = 1+24; 
SET @colindent1 = (SELECT CONCAT('i', @indent)); 
set @stmt = (SELECT @colindent1 FROM tableindex WHERE main=19);
 PREPARE thestmt FROM @stmt;
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): ..near 'i25' at line 1  AAAAHH! WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?

HOWEVER:

```
set @stmt = (SELECT i25 FROM tableindex WHERE main=19);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL to accomplish this.

Comment: _“However I am failing at this point”_ – no, you more likely failed way before that already, by using a data model that uses “numbered” column names, which in 99.999% of cases is a sure indicator that you’re doing something wrong.

Comment: Hi CBroe: Unfortunately this was a ported index/calculator using a x/y correlation to derive a predefined value.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff, Can you point me where and what dynamic SQL?  I am new to this.

Comment: Look at the Dynamic SQL - DECLARE is essentially that however I keep getting an error when I attempt the syntax.

Comment: @BrianB Could you please explain in more detail what you mean by "index calculator using an x/y correlation"? What does the data in your table actually represent, in simple terms? I've been following your other questions but can't figure out exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: the example you have here is NOT equal to the answer given by jim mc below. You have to set @stmt = '' as a string and not as a SQL statement

Answer (score 2):

To use variables to represent columns (or tables), you need to use PREPARE/EXECUTE.
Try something like this:

```
    SET @colindex1=(CONCAT(i, @indent);    
    SET @stmt = 'SELECT @colindex1 FROM tableindex WHERE main=19';
    PREPARE thestmt FROM @stmt;
    EXECUTE thestmt;
```

Comment: I am still having problems - here is a test

Comment: SEE QUESTION FOR TEST EXAMPLE

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
SET @stmt = CONCAT('SELECT i', @indent,' FROM tableindex WHERE main=19';
PREPARE thestmt FROM @stmt;
EXECUTE thestmt;
```